# PHP Class not found using namespaces

Tags: php, namespaces, composer-php

I can't find out why my classes won't load. I am using Composer for psr-4 autoloading and have been using it successfully. Here's how I have my classes setup:

/project
   /classes
      /feeds
         /pull
         /factory
   composer.json
   testMyFactory.php

feeds/factory/FeedFactory.php

```
namespace MyClasses\Feeds\Factory;

interface FeedFactory
{
    public function build($provider);
}
```

feeds/factory/PullFeedFactory.php

```
namespace MyClasses\Feeds\Factory;

use MyClasses\Feeds\Factory\FeedFactory;
use MyClasses\Feeds\Pull\Providers\One;

/**
 * Class FeedFactory
 */

class PullFeedFactory implements FeedFactory
{
    public function __construct(){}

    /**
     * Build provider object for factory
     * @param string $provider Type of feed provider to return
     * @return Object Provider object
     */

    public function build($provider) {
        switch ($provider) {
            case 'one':
                $provider = new One();
                break;
            default:
                $provider = new One`();
                break;
        }

        return $provider;
    }
}
```

project/feeds/pull/One.php

```
namespace MyClasses\Feeds\Pull\Providers;

class One
{
    public function pull() {
        echo 'Pull One';
    }
}
```

project/testMyFactory.php

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use MyClasses\Feeds\Factory\PullFeedFactory;  

$feed = new PullFeedFactory();
$feed->build('one');
$feed->pull();
```

project/composer.json

```
{
    "require": {
      //Remove for example       
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    },
    "require-dev": {
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "MyClasses\\": "./classes",
        }
    }
}
```

This is the error I keep getting `Class 'MyClasses\Feeds\Factory\PullFeedFactory' not found in /var/www/html/testPullFactory.php on line xx`

I have other classes that work in the Classes directory with autoload but for some reason cannot get this to work. I feel like it's something glaringly obvious but have been stuck on this for hours now.

UPDATE:

Updated to include my vendor/autoload.php file. Stil getting an error, although it's different now `Class 'MyClasses\Feeds\Pull\Providers\One' not found in /var/www/html/classes/Feeds/Factory/PullFeedFactory.php`

Comment: 1. You don't need to manually include any classes 2. Are you including `vendor/autoload.php` somewhere? 3. Which OS are you using? Is your FS case sensitive?

Comment: What @Federkun says. The whole idea behind Autoloading classes using PSR-4 is that you don't need to include file names anymore. They just work. In you "project/testMyFactory.php" file you need to `include vendor/autoload.php`. And if you don't have the vendor folder, run `composer dump-autoload` to create it

Comment: @Federkun So I was missing my autoload.php file. I'm still getting an error however, I updated my code.

Comment: Answer my last question about your file system please. Try renaming `feeds` directory in `Feeds`, same for `factory`, and so on.

Comment: @Federkun I'm running on this on windows OS using a ubuntu VM. Everything is already named uppercase.

Comment: You may need to update your question's code, because the error don't match with what you are showing us. You're trying to use `Providers` class. Is that located in `/var/www/html/classes/Feeds/Providers/Providers.php`?

Comment: @Federkun Sorry about that, that was just a class I was using to store static variables. I removed it for the sake of removing complexity for this question. Updated error.

Comment: Is the `One.php` class located in `Feeds/Pull/One.php` or `Feeds/Pull/Providers/One.php`?

Comment: It's in `Project/Feeds/Pull/One.php`

Comment: then the namespace for that file should be `namespace MyClasses\Feeds\Pull;`, and when you try to import it you `use MyClasses\Feeds\Pull\One;`

Comment: @Federkun that worked! Thanks!! So, I might be very ignorant about this but do namespaces have to match directory structure?

Comment: Yep. PSR-4 is a very simple specification, it's worth reading about it: https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/#3-examples

Answer (score 0):

in your composer.json, change to

```
"autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "MyClasses\\": "classes/",
        }
    }
```

Then, execute `composer dump-autoload`.